# Linear transformation of a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, linear-transformations

How can I show that $x'=hx(1-x)$ can be transformed to $y'=r-y^2$ using a linear transformation (i.e. $y=mx+b$)? I tackled the problem by substituting $x'$ with $y'/m$ and after algebraic manipulation, I cant get it to simplify down to a constant term minus a square term.

Comment: Is it written correctly?

Comment: sorry, let me correct it:

x' = hx(1-x) and y' = r-y^2

where h and r are constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write $y$ as a linear transformation of $x$ and take the derivative. Then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. From the linear transformation. Finally equate like constants with $r$, the coefficient of $y$ with $0$, and the coefficient of $y^2$ with $-1$, and solve for all your constants.

$$
\begin{align*}
y&= mx + b\\
\Rightarrow y' &= mx'\\
 &= mhx(1-x)\\
 &= mh\frac{y-b}{m}\left(1 - \frac{y-b}{m}\right)\\
&=h(y-b)\left(\frac{m - (y-b)}{m}\right) \\
&= hy -hb -\frac{h(y-b)^2}{m}\\
&= hy(1 + \frac{2b}{m}) - hb( 1 + \frac{b}{m}) - \frac hmy^2
\end{align*}
$$

Equating like terms gives you:

$$
\begin{align*}
m &= h\\
b &= -\frac h2 \\
r &= \frac {h^2}{4} 
\end{align*}
$$